Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI 404 error when posting
I am running this snippet of code from the module synopsis using strawberry Perl :
use Mojolicious::Lite;
 
# Because the route name "echo" matches the "x-mojo-name", this route
# will be moved under "basePath", resulting in "POST /api/echo"
post "/echo" => sub {
 
  # Validate input request or return an error document
  my $c = shift->openapi->valid_input or return;
 
  # Generate some data
  my $data = {body => $c->req->json};
 
  # Validate the output response and render it to the user agent
  # using a custom "openapi" handler.
  $c->render(openapi => $data);
}, "echo";
 
# Load specification and start web server
plugin OpenAPI => {url => "data:///swagger.yaml"};
app->start;
 
__DATA__
@@ swagger.yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info: { version: "0.8", title: "Echo Service" }
schemes: ["https"]
basePath: "/api"
paths:
  /echo:
   post:
     x-mojo-name: "echo"
     parameters:
     - { in: "body", name: "body", schema: { type: "object" } }
     responses:
       200:
         description: "Echo response"
         schema: { type: "object" } 

Then run the script as a daemon which listen on port 3000 after that i am running Curl as the below from the same machine
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/echo -H "Content-Type : application/json" -d "{ \"key\" : \"value\" }"

my expection to render the __DATA__ section but i am getting this error
{"errors":[{"message":"Expected  - got *\/*.","path":"\/header\/Accept"}],"status":400}

any idea what could be the problem ?

I don't have time to debug this right now, but when I run into these problems I usually start with the mojo routes command to verify that the paths are defined as I expected: https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Command::routes

Thanks i found the problem it was on the curl  the Content-Type and :  had a space which make this error changing it to :curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/echo -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d "{ "body" : 34 }"  solved the issue

Is your YAML in the __DATA__ section malformed? I'm pretty sure you need another tab behind the - after parameters:.

@smith You should post that as an Answer
